# Should I find a workaround for missing front page of website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The front page of the website at [www.violinschool.org](https://www.violinschool.org) is not showing up. I think it might be a conflict with a wordpress plugin called 'content views pro'.

I can't remove that plugin as it would destroy the two main pages I've created for our learning content. So I'm wondering if there is a way of replacing the front page of the wordpress theme instead.

Does that sound like a reasonable workaround, and do you have any idea how I'd go about doing it?

Thanks so much for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem caused by option **Force JavaScript in <head>** of the plugin Autoptimize.
Just simply uncheck that option to solve this issue.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This solved the issue perfectly! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

it looks like your problem comes from `.preloader` so i would recomend you to add small css edit to your page style files. try to add `.preloader{display:none;}`

Comment: This is only a hot fix for your website just to get it back online. I would recommend you to test every page that might be using .preloader. At least  check pages that are important for your busines.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful feedback! This has solved the problem of the page not displaying, which is great.

Comment: It does seem that the background image I had on the front page now doesn't display - I am not sure if this is as a result of changing the .preloader or not - but either way, at least the pages is showing! Thank you very much for the suggestion - yes absolutely I'll check the other key pages to make sure this hasn't caused any other issues. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @DavidJ Good to see you got your background image visible again :)

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Lööri said, the preloader is preventing the rest of the page from being shown, eventhough it has been loaded correctly.

Either try to set the class to display:none or remove the component completely, considering this might cause issues for your website in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think is just hidden under the preloader class. That could be caused because your jquery library is clashing with something.